# Email template problem

Tags: magento-1.9, email-templates

In this mail template I can't able to get **Customer Name & Store Title**

```
public function updatecustomerAction(){

    $sellerData = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
    $sellerId = $sellerData->getId();
    $seller_mail = $sellerData->getEmail();

        $collection = Mage::getModel('followup/followup')->getCollection()
                            ->addFieldToFilter('seller_id', $sellerId)
                            ->addFieldToFilter('seller_email', $seller_mail);

    foreach($collection as $item){
        $mycustomer_email =  $item->getCustomerEmail();
        $mycustomer_name = $item->getCustomerName();
        //return $mycustomer;
        $template_id = 'customer_update';        
                     $email_to = $mycustomer_email;
                     $seller_store = $sellerData->getStoreTitle();

                     $custom_variable = $mycustomer_name;
                     $custom_variable1 = $seller_store;

                     $email_template  = Mage::getModel('core/email_template')->loadDefault($template_id);
                     $email_template_variables = array(
                        'custom_variable' => $custom_variable,
                        'custom_variable1' => $custom_variable1);

                     $sender_name = Mage::getStoreConfig(Mage_Core_Model_Store::XML_PATH_STORE_STORE_NAME);
                     $sender_email = Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_general/email');
                     $email_template->setSenderName($sender_name);
                     $email_template->setSenderEmail($sender_email);
                     $email_template->send($email_to, $email_template_variables);
    }



                     $this->_redirectReferer();
        Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess('Done');

}
```

What is the Problem on this?

Comment: What is the code you're using in the email template to display the values?

Comment: Yesy I ma using this custom_variable & custom_variable1 for displaying

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a lot of un-needed assigning and re-assigning of variables there which is confusing things. This should work:

```
public function updatecustomerAction(){

    $sellerData = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
    $sellerId = $sellerData->getId();
    $seller_mail = $sellerData->getEmail();
    $seller_store = $sellerData->getStoreTitle();

    $collection = Mage::getModel('followup/followup')->getCollection()
        ->addFieldToFilter('seller_id', $sellerId)
        ->addFieldToFilter('seller_email', $seller_mail);

    foreach($collection as $item){
        $email_template  = Mage::getModel('core/email_template')->loadDefault('customer_update');
        $email_template_variables = array(
            'customerName' => $item->getCustomerName(),
            'sellerStore' => $seller_store
        );
        $email_template->setSenderName(Mage::getStoreConfig(Mage_Core_Model_Store::XML_PATH_STORE_STORE_NAME));
        $email_template->setSenderEmail(Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_general/email'));
        $email_template->send($item->getCustomerEmail(), $email_template_variables);
    }

    $this->_redirectReferer();
    Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess('Done');

}
```

Then in your email template use `{{var customerName}}` and `{{var sellerStore}}` to display the assigned values.

Comment: Still Same Not Getting Customer Name & Seller Store